# Convert new Date() to weekday string eg 'Thursday' using date-fns

Tags: date-fns

I'm using date-fns I would like to convert new Date(2020,1,10) to 'Thursday'. I'm trying to use

```
dateFns.format(new Date(2020,1,10),'dddd')
```

but it returns 0001?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use this for full Day name:

```
import {format} from 'date-fns';

format(new Date(2020,1,10), 'EEEE')
```

Comment: `EEEE` is the correct answer, but I made the same mistake because of their documentation https://date-fns.org/v1.30.1/docs/format

Comment: The format string format changed in date-fns v1 -> v2, make sure to switch to the correct version of the documentation in the top right corner, e.g. https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/format

Answer (score 1):

This also works:
`format(new Date(2020,1,10), 'iiii')`

Answer (score 0):

For me using `date ("2022-10-29")` and `format(new Date(date), 'EEEE')`
showed wrong weekday Friday instead of Saturday (I am Central Time), from my understanding I need to provide time to get correct weekday.

for some reason this using different "Month Day, Year" format this worked:   `{format(parseISO(date), "MMMM d, yyyy")}` => October 29, 2022

Since I had time in different variable, I have combined, date and time `{format(new Date(date + "T" + time + "Z"), "EEEE")}` this seem to work, shows correct weekday: Saturday

Answer (score 0):

`"dddd"` only works in older versions of date-fns (< 2.0.0) for getting the day of the week. In newer versions, `"dddd"` is replaced with `"EEEE"`.